# Get called function name in destructor

Tags: php, class

is it possible to get the called function name in destructor ?

```
class My_class {

    function my_func() {
        echo 'Hii';
    }

    function your_func() {
        echo 'Hii';
    }

    function __destruct() {
        echo $the_called_func_name;
    }
}


$bar = new my_class();
$bar->my_func();
```

is it possible to get the name '`my_func`' in the destructor ?

if we used

```
echo __FUNCTION__;
```

it will give

```
__destruct
```

i want

```
my_func
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to accomplish? In other words: why? I am sure this is not necessary

Comment: its just for logging that which function has been accesed. Instead of calling log function in each function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Since `my_func` is dynamical, you can use function overload (a.k.a magic method) `__call()`

```
class My_Class
{

   private $methods = array(); 


   public function __call($method, array $args)
   {
      array_push($this->methods, $method);
   }

   public function getMethods()
   {
      return $this->methods;
   }

   public function __destruct()
   {
      // Off course, you should improve this 
      print_r($this->getMethods());
   }
}

// Usage:

$foo = new My_Class();
$foo->my_func(); // Output Array(0 => 'my_func')
```

Answer (score 1):

> its just for logging that which function has been accesed. Instead of calling log function in each function.

It's not easily possible without adding code to the methods or using a separate tool for debugging and profiling.

Note that the proposed solutions with `__call` don't work with existing public methods, in the end it would get more complicated than just adding `log(__METHOD__)` to each method.

What you are looking for is basically [Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) which is not terribly supported in PHP. The framework Flow3 uses annotations and reflection to add aspects dynamically. Their [Logging Example](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/AspectOrientedProgramming.html) is a perfect illustration of your use case:

```
namespace Example\MyPackage;

/**
 * A logging aspect
 *
 * @Flow\Aspect
 */
class LoggingAspect {

        /**
         * @var \TYPO3\Flow\Log\LoggerInterface A logger implementation
         */
        protected $logger;

        /**
         * For logging we need a logger, which we will get injected automatically by
         * the Object Manager
         *
         * @param \TYPO3\Flow\Log\SystemLoggerInterface $logger The System Logger
         * @return void
         */
        public function injectSystemLogger(\TYPO3\Flow\Log\SystemLoggerInterface ⏎
                $systemLogger) {
                $this->logger = $systemLogger;
        }

        /**
         * Before advice, logs all access to public methods of our package
         *
         * @param  \TYPO3\Flow\AOP\JoinPointInterface $joinPoint: The current join point
         * @return void
         * @Flow\Before("method(public Example\MyPackage\.*->.*())")
         */
        public function logMethodExecution(\TYPO3\Flow\AOP\JoinPointInterface $joinPoint) {
                $logMessage = 'The method ' . $joinPoint->getMethodName() . ' in class ' .
                        $joinPoint->getClassName() . ' has been called.';
                $this->logger->log($logMessage);
        }
}
```

The important line is this:

```
@Flow\Before("method(public Example\MyPackage\.*->.*())")
```

it tells the framework to call `logMethodExecution` before any method call in any class of the `Example\MyPackage` namespace.

So, with **Flow3** you can do it. But implementing a similar behaviour by yourself without an AOP framework is bound to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
class My_class {

    function my_func() {
        echo 'Hii';
    }

    function your_func() {
        echo 'Hii';
    }

    function __destruct() {
        self::my_func();
        // my_func called
    }
}


$bar = new my_class();
$bar->my_func();
```

If you mean function name, use `__call` for object function and `__callStatic` for static function.